# Regex to add a 0 to the 2nd digit after comma if missing

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I want to add a **0** to the **2nd digit** after comma in case it's missing. For example: Having the values **-2,3; 45,5; 3.000,0;** and replacing to **-2,30; 45,50; 3.000,00**.
I thought about matching with `.*,\d{1}` in an IF statement first (i.e. checking if the value has just 1 digit after the comma) and then replacing with the pattern `(.*)` and replace function `${1}0`, but this seems to be adding two zeroes instead of one, e.g. resulting into **-2,300; 45,500**, etc..

Edit: I just realized that I could also just concatenate the string with a "0" if regex matching returns true.

Comment: Are the numbers fed to the regex replace function separate strings? Then use `(,\d)$` to replace with `${1}0`

Comment: Thanks for your input sir, I just realized that I could also just concatenate the String with a "0" when regex match returns true.

Comment: Yes. Or, use the above one-step solution. See https://regex101.com/r/60lGqp/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to check if a string ends with a comma and one digit. You can use

```cs
(,\d)$
```

Replace with `${1}0`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/60lGqp/2).

Now, the consuming part will never match an empty string and will match

- `(,\d)` - a comma and a digit (Capturing group 1)
- `$`  - end of string.

`${1}0` will replace the match with the Group 1 value with `0` after it .